# How do I invoke this method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I define my method

```
var setAge = function (newAge) { 
   this.age = newAge;
};
```

I make susan

```
var susan = new Object();
susan.age = 25;
susan.setAge = setAge;
```

I invoke the method

```
susan.setAge(35);
```

So, Why is line 3 of the "i make susan" blockquote necessary? (susan.setAge = setAge).

Pretend we remove that line. Why can't javascript intuitively recognize that susan.setAge(35) is referring to the setAge method in my first blockquote? (I feel as if the code could be simpler)

Do we need strict definitions so that we don't accidentally invoke another method?
It's late, I'm completely new, and my brain's foggy. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Because setAge is not a method? It's just a function at that point.

Comment: It's like you want a function to become a global method property for any object. I mean forget javascript, is there any language that you can actually do that?

Comment: @BatuZet It's been [proposed for rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6974), so it's not an intrinsically crazy idea.  Certainly not how javascript works, though!

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't javascript intuitively recognize that susan.setAge(35) is referring to the setAge method in my first blockquote? (i feel as if the code could be simpler)

I suppose javascript *could* be implemented in that way, but it isn't.  I've seen a [proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/289) for a similar feature in rust, that sparked quite a lot of discussion.

> i feel as if the code could be simpler

In addition to the [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method that javascript functions have, you might want to look into how object [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) work:

```
//A new type of object, called Person
var Person = function(){};
Person.prototype.setAge = function(age) { this.age = age };

var susan = new Person();
susan.setAge(35);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the `susan` part, the JS engine has no idea that you want to use `susan` as the `this` in your function. I think you're making a strange assumption that the `susan.setAge = setAge` would modify the behavior of the function you originally defined, which was completely unrelated to `susan`.

Generally speaking, when you call a function, whatever appears before the `.` is what will be used as the `this` inside the function (unless it is a "bound function"). If you don't use the dot notation and just call the function directly, `this` will be the global object (in "sloppy mode") or `null` (in "strict mode").

An alternative way to call the function and get the result you are expecting is to do:

```
setAge.call(susan, 35);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're confused by the result because it is in line with what you're expecting.  That is, in the end, you expect susan's age to be set to 35, because you called the setAge() function to do so, and you called it using susan.  But that is not really what is going on.  Actually what's happening is more along the lines of...

1. you define a global function, `setAge()` - you could invoke this without `susan`.  Doing so would invoke it in the global context, which would add a property `window.age` if it didn't already exist.
2. you define a global object, `susan`.  Really this is in the global context, so now you have `window.susan` (object), and `window.setAge` (function).
3. you define a property on `susan` called `setAge`, assigning it a value of the function you defined in step 1.  The name of this property on `susan` could be anything.  It is just an alias for some value, and in this case you have made it an alias for a function, which happens to go by the same name.
4. you retrieve `susan`'s `setAge` property value, which is a function, and execute it, passing it `35` as a parameter - ultimately the global function `setAge()` is executed in the scope of `susan` (meaning `this` in `setAge()` is essentially replaced with `susan` when `setAge()` is executed)

To alleviate some confusion, try changing

```
susan.setAge = setAge;
```

to

```
susan.AgeSetter = setAge;
```

You'll now get a javascript error if you try to call `susan.setAge(35);` because it was not defined.  The object `susan` doesn't have a property `setAge`, but rather a property `AgeSetter`.  And when you call `susan.AgeSetter(35)` everything works again.

---

I think the way you're expecting this to work is more along the lines of the utility methods [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Using call or apply, your global function `setAge()` would not change, nor would `susan`, except `susan` would have no property `setAge()`.  Instead you could invoke `setAge()`, forcing the context to be `susan`, using either `call` or `apply` (for now you just need to know they're basically the same but you invoke call with explicit params and apply with an array of params).

So the script would look like...

```
var setAge = function (newAge) {
    this.age = newAge;
};

var susan = new Object();

susan.age = 25;

setAge.call(susan, 35);

alert(susan.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would break variable scoping.

Initially, `setAge` is just a variable and it's value is an anonymous function.

The `setAge` property of the `susan` object isn't defined until you make it equal to the value of the variable that was defined outside of the object's scope. If JavaScript intuitively knew that `susan.setAge` was the same as `setAge` (defined outside of the `susan` `Object`), then it would mean that you couldn't define any variables outside of an object definition without worrying that they would collide with an object's properties.